# How can I include the number of the section and the subsection in the output of a \ref command?

Tags: cross-referencing

Is it possible to include the **number of the section** and the **number of the subsection** in the `\ref` command? If I want to cross-reference a theorem, I currently only get the number of the theorem-like environment, for example,
`theorem 1`.

If the number of the section where the theorem is located is `x` and correspondingly the number of the subsection is `y`, I would like to have the output of `\ref` to be `x.y.1` and not just `1`. Is this possible to achieve?

I will add an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,DIV=10,BCOR=8mm,headsepline,footsepline,
               leqno,fleqn]{scrreprt}
%*
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%*
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{Defi}{subsection}
\makeatother
%*
\newtheoremstyle{def_style} % name
{}                          % space above
{}                          % space below
{\upshape}                  % body font
{}                          % indent amount
{\bfseries}                 % theorem head font
{:}                         % punctuation after theorem head
{\newline}                  % space after theorem head
{}                          % theorem head spec
                            % (can be left empty, meaning 'normal')
\theoremstyle{def_style}
\newtheorem{Defi}{Definition}
\newtheorem{Exa}[Defi]{Example}
\newtheorem{Thm}[Defi]{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{Prf}{Proof}
%*
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
%*
\begin{document}
%*
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%*
\chapter*{Part 1}
%*
\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{Section 1}
\label{sec: Section 1}
%*
\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\label{ssec: Subsection 1}
%*
\begin{Defi} \label {thm: d1}
This ist the first definition in subsection 1 and section 1.
\end{Defi}
%*
\begin{Thm} \label{thm: s1}
This is the first theorem in section 1, subsection 1.
\end{Thm}
%*
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\label{ssec: Subsection 2}
%*
\begin{Defi} \label{thm: d2}
This is the first definition in subsection 2.
\end{Defi}
%*
\begin{Exa} \label{thm: b1}
This is an example.
\end{Exa}
%*
\section{Section 2}
\label{sec: Section 2}
%*
\subsection{Subsection 1 in Section 2}
\label{ssec: Subsection 1 in Section 2}
%*
\begin{Exa} \label{thm: b2}
This is an example in subsection 1 and section 2.
\end{Exa}
%*
\begin{Defi} \label{thm: d3}
This is a definition. We refer to definition~\ref{thm: d2}.
\end{Defi}
%*
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to include section and subsection number just in the `\ref` command or also in the Definition numbering as well?

Comment: The section- and subsection-number should only be included into the ref-command. Definitions and theorems should be displayed as in the example that I added.

Comment: The section- and subsection-number should only be included into the ref-command. Definitions and theorems should be displayed as in the example that I added. When I use the option "\newtheorem{Defi}{Definition}[section]" as proposed, then the section and subsection number will be included in the \ref-command, but also in the numbering of the definitions and theorems. I just want to have the references including section- and subsection-numbers.

Comment: To be honest, as a reader I would find this numbering/referencing  style a bit confusing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Whatever else you choose to do, do *not* load the `latexsym` package -- especially as you load the `amssymb` package.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE. I believe the following:

```latex
\labelformat{Defi}{\thesubsection.\arabic{Defi}}
```

should do what you want. This will also print the “*section*.*subsection*.“ prefix when you use `\ref`  for a definition or an example, because you defined `Defi`, `Exa`, and `Thm` to all share the same counter, named `Defi`.

In case your LaTeX release is so old that it doesn't have the `\labelformat` command, use the following before `\labelformat{Defi}{...}`:

```latex
\providecommand*{\labelformat}[1]{\expandafter\def\csname p@#1\endcsname##1}
```

This way, `\labelformat` will use that definition only if it is not already defined (normally, by the LaTeX kernel).

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{Defi}{subsection}
\makeatother

\newtheoremstyle{def_style} % name
{}                          % space above
{}                          % space below
{\upshape}                  % body font
{}                          % indent amount
{\bfseries}                 % theorem head font
{:}                         % punctuation after theorem head
{\newline}                  % space after theorem head
{}                          % theorem head spec
                            % (can be left empty, meaning 'normal')
\theoremstyle{def_style}
\newtheorem{Defi}{Definition}
\newtheorem{Exa}[Defi]{Example}
\newtheorem{Thm}[Defi]{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{Prf}{Proof}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\labelformat{Defi}{\thesubsection.\arabic{Defi}}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Chapter 1}

\section{Section 1}
\label{sec: Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\label{ssec: Subsection 1}

\begin{Defi} \label {thm: d1}
This ist the first definition in subsection 1 and section 1.
\end{Defi}

\begin{Thm} \label{thm: s1}
This is the first theorem in section 1, subsection 1.
\end{Thm}

\subsection{Subsection 2}
\label{ssec: Subsection 2}

\begin{Defi} \label{thm: d2}
This is the first definition in subsection 2.
\end{Defi}

\begin{Exa} \label{thm: b1}
This is an example.
\end{Exa}

\section{Section 2}
\label{sec: Section 2}

\subsection{Subsection 1 in Section 2}
\label{ssec: Subsection 1 in Section 2}

\begin{Exa} \label{thm: b2}
This is an example in subsection 1 and section 2.
\end{Exa}

\begin{Defi} \label{thm: d3}
This is a definition. We refer to definition~\ref{thm: d2} and
theorem~\ref{thm: s1}.
\end{Defi}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you want the “qualified numbering” (with “*section*.*subsection*.“ prefix) to *also* be used when definitions, examples and theorems are stated, replace the `\labelformat{Defi}{\thesubsection.\arabic{Defi}}` line with:

```latex
\renewcommand{\theDefi}{\thesubsection.\arabic{Defi}}
```

and you'll get this (I intentionally don't reproduce the irrelevant chapter title again):

[image]

However, a more idiomatic way to achieve the same is probably to remove this:

```latex
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{Defi}{subsection}
\makeatother
```

and declare the `subsection` counter as a parent of the `Defi` counter:

```latex
\newtheorem{Defi}{Definition}[subsection]
```

(then the output is the same as above).

Note: please don't include irrelevant packages in your minimal working examples and use LaTeX standard classes when the class doesn't matter (`article` unless you really want to see the effect with `\chapter`... as may be the case here, hence my choice of the `report` document class).

Comment: @DieterPeschk Since your LaTeX kernel appears not to have `\labelformat`, I added a definition you can use (this is the current definition in the LaTeX kernel). You should have told me that `\labelformat` wasn't defined on your installation. Otherwise, how am I supposed to find this out?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\labelformat`, but this method for cross-referencing is very awkward, because the reader has to find out where a certain subsection is, instead of just looking at the statement number.

I would simply number statements uniquely across sections, so

```
\newtheorem{Defi}{Definition}[section]
```

Anyway, here's a solution to your problem that will remove a `0.` if a statement happens to be between `\section` and the first `\subsection` (adding to complexity in lookups, though).

```latex
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  11pt,
  DIV=10,
  BCOR=8mm,
  headsepline,
  footsepline,
  leqno,
  fleqn
]{scrreprt}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{latexsym} % not needed with amssymb
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{def_style} % name
{}                          % space above
{}                          % space below
{\upshape}                  % body font
{}                          % indent amount
{\bfseries}                 % theorem head font
{:}                         % punctuation after theorem head
{\newline}                  % space after theorem head
{}                          % theorem head spec
                            % (can be left empty, meaning 'normal')
\theoremstyle{def_style}
\newtheorem{Defi}{Definition}
\newtheorem{Exa}[Defi]{Example}
\newtheorem{Thm}[Defi]{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{Prf}{Proof}

\counterwithin*{Defi}{section}    % reset Defi when incrementing section
\counterwithin*{Defi}{subsection} % reset Defi when incrementing subsection

\labelformat{Defi}{%
  \arabic{section}.%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \arabic{subsection}.\fi
  \arabic{Defi}%
}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Part 1}

\section{Section 1}
\label{sec:Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\label{ssec:Subsection 1}

\begin{Defi} \label {thm:d1}
This ist the first definition in subsection 1 and section 1.
\end{Defi}

\begin{Thm} \label{thm:s1}
This is the first theorem in section 1, subsection 1.
\end{Thm}

\subsection{Subsection 2}
\label{ssec:Subsection 2}

\begin{Defi} \label{thm:d2}
This is the first definition in subsection 2.
\end{Defi}

\begin{Exa} \label{thm:b1}
This is an example.
\end{Exa}

\section{Section 2}
\label{sec:Section 2}

\subsection{Subsection 1 in Section 2}
\label{ssec:Subsection 1 in Section 2}

\begin{Exa} \label{thm:b2}
This is an example in subsection 1 and section 2.
\end{Exa}

\begin{Defi} \label{thm:d3}
This is a definition. We refer to definition~\ref{thm:d2}.
\end{Defi}

\end{document}
```

I made other fixes to your code: `\@addtoreset` has been made available as `\counterwithin`; without the `*` the command also modifies the counter's representation, whereas `\counterwithin*` only adds to the reset pool.

[image]

I'd avoid spaces in labels, because editors take spaces as good places to break lines in the input representation and you risk splitting the label across lines, making for difficult lookup.

Note that `\pagenumbering{arabic}` and `\setcounter{section}{0}` are completely useless if you *number* your chapters, which you *should* do.

If you don't want to number your chapters, do

```
\stepcounter{section}\addtocounter{section}{-1}
```

or the related counters would not reset.

Comment: When I compile your suggestion, I receive error-messages like "undefined control sequence (statements counterwithin and statement labelformat).

Comment: @DieterPeschk You seem to have a quite old release of LaTeX.

Comment: The LaTeX-release that I have, is from the year 2018 (a miktex-distribution).

Comment: @DieterPeschk Upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote (with some paraphrasing applied):

> Suppose a theorem numbered `1` is located in a section numbered `x` and a subsection numbered `y`. I would like the cross-reference to that theorem to look like `x.y.1` and not just `1`.

Since you set up a counter called `Defi` for the theorem-like environments, the easiest way I know of to achieve your objective is to add the instruction

```
\renewcommand{\p@Defi}{\thesubsection.}
```

to the preamble. The `\p@Defi` macro is created automatically by LaTeX at the time the counter `Defi` is created. The macro is empty by default; it may be changed via a `\renewcommand` instruction.

In following compilable example, I've stripped down your code to what I consider a minimum. This makes it easier, I believe, to understand the essentials. I've loaded the `hyperref` and `cleveref` packages mostly to make it easier to see what the cross-references look like.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,DIV=10,BCOR=8mm, 
   headsepline,footsepline,leqno,fleqn]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%%\usepackage{latexsym} % don't load this package!!!
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

%% Just for this example:
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{definition} % no need to be too fancy for this example...
\newtheorem{Defi}{Definition}
\newtheorem{Exa}[Defi]{Example}
\newtheorem{Thm}[Defi]{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{Prf}{Proof}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{Defi}{subsection}
\renewcommand{\p@Defi}{\thesubsection.} % <-- new!
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1} \label{ssec:Subsection1}
\begin{Defi} \label{thm:dx1}
This is the first theorem-like environment of subsection \ref{ssec:Subsection1}.
\end{Defi}

\subsection{Subsection 2} \label{ssec:Subsection2}
\begin{Defi} \label{thm:dx2}
This is the first theorem-like environment of subsection \ref{ssec:Subsection2}.
\end{Defi}
\begin{Exa} \label{thm:ey2}
This is an example.
\end{Exa}
\begin{Thm} \label{thm:tz2}
This is a theorem.
\end{Thm}

\section{Section 2}
We now cross-reference \cref{thm:dx2,thm:ey2,thm:tz2}.
\end{document}
```